# ASP.NET MVC Complex Model Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

I have a complex Model

```
public class ComplexModel
{

    public UserModel userModel;

    public ExtraInfoModel extraModel;
}
```

where

UserModel may have required fields

as in:

```
public class UserModel
{

     [Required]
     public string email;
}
```

how do I validate ComplexModel to make sure that the data annotations on its member models are being taken into the account in ComplexModel validation?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

Here's my exact scenario. When I call ModelState.IsValid in a controller action on ManageProfileModel regardless of whether "SelectedValue" of ListModelRequired member of GeneralInfoModel was set or not the model state is valid.

```
public class ManageProfileModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Experience is required")]
    public int LevelOfExperienceTypeID { get; set; }
    public GeneralInfoModel GeneralInfoModel { get; set; }
}

public class GeneralInfoModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Profile Headline")]
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Signature")]
    public string Signature { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ListModelRequired LevelOfExperience { get; set; }
}

public class ListModel
{
    public ListModel()
    {
    }

    public ListModel(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public ListModel(string name, string selectedValue):this(name)
    {
        this.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
    }

    public ListModel(string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> members):this(name)
    {
        this.Members = members;
    }

    public ListModel(string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> members, string selectedValue)
        : this(name, members)
    {
        this.SelectedValue = selectedValue;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Members { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class ListModelRequired : ListModel
{
    [Required]
    public override string SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public ListModelRequired():base()
    {
    }

    public ListModelRequired(string name):base(name)
    {
    }

    public ListModelRequired(string name, string selectedValue):base(name,selectedValue)
    {
    }

    public ListModelRequired(string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> members)
        : base(name, members)
    {
    }

    public ListModelRequired(string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> members, string selectedValue)
        : base(name, members,selectedValue)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the default model binder gets this right, validating submodels that use the data annotations.  What problem are you actually having it with it?  For example, I have something similar to:

```
public class OnlineDonationModel
{
     [Required]
     public decimal? Amount { get; set; }

     public ContactModel Contact { get; set; }
}

public class ContactModel
{
     [Required]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Address { get; set; }

     ...
}
```

Comment: I just posted an update to my problem. It doesn't look like DefaultModelBinder is working in my situation. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only difference I see is that you are making the actual submodel instance required.  I think if you have required properties on the submodel those will still bubble up so you shouldn't need that.  Try removing the required attribute on the submodel instance and see if it changes.

Comment: this is what i thought as well. but it didn't. so, out of trying to find a fix, i tried adding [Required] on the member of the top level model.