# Asp.NET WebApi complex model validation

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, model

I have a very similar problem to this question ([/q/4036259](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4036259/1495932)).
My model looks somewhat like this:

**SearchModel.cs**

```
[DataContract]
public class SearchModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "sort")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "e_sort")]
    public SortModel Sort { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "offset")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "e_offset")]
    public int Offset { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "limit")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "e_limit")]
    public int Limit { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "query")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "e_query")]
    public string Query { get; set; }
}
```

**SortModel.cs**

```
[DataContract]
public class SortModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "e_sort_type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "asc")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "e_sort_asc")]
    public bool Asc { get; set; }
}
```

When i send something like this:

```
{
   "sort" : {
     "type" : "rank" 
   },
   "offset" : 0,
   "limit" : 10,
   "query" : "stackoverflow"
}
```

I'm getting validation error in my ModelState which is the correct behaviour but the ErrorMessage is empty. The error i'm getting is as follows

> {"Required property 'asc' not found in JSON. Path 'sort', line 5, position 5."}
>
> Error key points to "model.sort" which is fine, but the ErrorMessage property from Required attribute seems to be doing nothing.

Anyone has any suggestion as to what might be causing this?

Comment: You are not sending a sort asc. You are only sending a sort type. have you considered this?

Comment: I think the question is that he is not getting custom error message instead of default one

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, I know i'm not sending this and i want custom ErrorMessage when it happens which is not working, that's the problem.